# How can I change this comment plugin to work at the start of the line?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim

I got this from [voyeg3r's gist](https://gist.github.com/voyeg3r/223f148a115c17a02a15660cc7335f4c)
He and [@dave-kennedy](https://github.com/dave-kennedy) made it 3 years ago.
I am here because I couldn't contact them

Can someone help me add a feature such that
this vimscript code puts comment out signs at the first of each line?

```
let s:comment_map = {
    \   "c": '\/\/',
    \   "cpp": '\/\/',
    \   "go": '\/\/',
    \   "java": '\/\/',
    \   "javascript": '\/\/',
    \   "lua": '--',
    \   "scala": '\/\/',
    \   "php": '\/\/',
    \   "python": '#',
    \   "ruby": '#',
    \   "rust": '\/\/',
    \   "sh": '#',
    \   "desktop": '#',
    \   "fstab": '#',
    \   "conf": '#',
    \   "profile": '#',
    \   "bashrc": '#',
    \   "bash_profile": '#',
    \   "mail": '>',
    \   "eml": '>',
    \   "bat": 'REM',
    \   "ahk": ';',
    \   "vim": '"',
    \   "tex": '%',
    \ }

function! ToggleComment()
    if has_key(s:comment_map, &filetype)
        let comment_leader = s:comment_map[&filetype]
        if getline('.') =~ '^\s*$'
            " Skip empty line
            return
        endif
        if getline('.') =~ '^\s*' . comment_leader
            " Uncomment the line
            execute 'silent s/\v\s*\zs' . comment_leader . '\s*\ze//'
        else
            " Comment the line
            execute 'silent s/\v^(\s*)/\1' . comment_leader . ' /'
        endif
    else
        echo "No comment leader found for filetype"
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>t :call ToggleComment()<CR>
vnoremap <Leader>t :call ToggleComment()<CR>
```

PS: this works perfectly. But i need the extra feature which will put comment out signs at the first of each line

for example:
if i comment out this code

```
     #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

                          int main() {
    cout << "hello world" << "\n";
             }
```

it will be like this

```
//     #include <iostream>
//using namespace std;

//                          int main() {
//    cout << "hello world" << "\n";
//             }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'comment out signs at the first of each line'. Could you add some example code with how the plugin puts the  comments signs and a second example of how you would like them to be? Thanks! (P.S. I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but there is a [plugin for commenting](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary))

Comment: sorry.. its not a plugin.. just custom code in vimrc.. updated the post.. please check

Comment: Hi, I'm still confused as you say it 'works perfectly' but you want to add a feature. So my question is what does the vimrc code do currently? Also the plugin I mentioned in the last comment does what you're trying to do here - it gives the `gc` operator to toggle the commenting one lines, and you can use it with any motion e.g. `gcip` to comment inside paragraph, or `gc5j` to comment current line and also 5 lines below.

Comment: i meant.. my vimrc comment out code works fine.. but it lacks the feature of putting the comment out signs at the very first of each line

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

```
            " Comment the line
            execute 'silent s/\v^(\s*)/\1' . comment_leader . ' /'
```

to

```
            " Comment the line
            execute 'silent s/^/\1' . comment_leader . '/'
```

so that it substitutes at the beginning of the line rather than after any space. The uncomment pattern needs similar modifications: replace `\v\s*\zs` with `^`, and remove `\s*\ze` entirely.

---

For extra niceness, use `escape(comment_leader, '/\')` in the substitute commands; then the configuration doesn't need to escape the slashes.

Comment: your code works but it causes indentation error.. it puts comment out signs at the very first. it's true.. when i uncomment certain lines, it deletes indentation before each line & pulls the whole line or block of code at the first respectively

Comment: The uncomment probably needs to be adjusted. Try replacing `\v\s*\zs` with `^` and remove the `\s*\ze`

Comment: it works.. thank you very much :)

Comment: my code needs some fix.. it doesn't support conf, mail, tex and so on.. i mean it doesn't comment out these files

Comment: @MegaBang you probably should ask a new question. Try using `:debug` if you can. And make sure you post details on the steps you take, what happens, and what you expect.

Comment: the solution you have given.. it has a problem.. when i comment out block of code and uncomment it.. extra one character space is applied at the first of each line

Comment: if you comment & then uncomment multiple times, you will see the difference.. everytime extra one character space is added at the very first of each line

Comment: Fixed. There's an extra space in the original which I have removed. You may want to read `:help expr` and generally practice some vimscript. Learn Vimscript the Hard Way is a nice but somewhat dated resource to practice the essentials.

Comment: but you have removed one feature.. the main source code from the gist comments out 1. it puts the sign 2. adds a space after that sign.. when it uncomments, it removes the sign with the space.. in short, uncommenting makes the code exactly as previous

Comment: @MegaBang I don’t really have more time to spend on this. I’m sure you can tweak the commands to use exactly a space after the comment leader based on the code

Comment: i just wanted the comment out signs at the first of each line.. if it doesn't support tex, mail, that's fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth a mention that you can also visually select the lines and
then do:

```
:'<,'>norm I//
```

to apply the normal mode command `I`nsert at the start of the line the
commenting out characters (and remember to put a space after: `//` )

Without visual selection you could use line addresses:

```
" comment lines 10 through 20 
:10,20norm I//
```

```
" comment relative lines -10 through +20
:-10,+20norm I//
```