# How can I make this comment script work for certain filetypes?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim

I got this code from [voyeg3r's gist](https://gist.github.com/voyeg3r/223f148a115c17a02a15660cc7335f4c) 
@d-ben-knoble helped me add a feature I wanted in [this QA](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31736/36876).

Now I want this code to support commenting out certain filetypes like conf, mail, tex and so on.

My edited vimrc code:

```
let s:comment_map = {
    \   "c": '\/\/',
    \   "cpp": '\/\/',
    \   "go": '\/\/',
    \   "java": '\/\/',
    \   "javascript": '\/\/',
    \   "lua": '--',
    \   "scala": '\/\/',
    \   "php": '\/\/',
    \   "python": '#',
    \   "ruby": '#',
    \   "rust": '\/\/',
    \   "sh": '#',
    \   "desktop": '#',
    \   "fstab": '#',
    \   "conf": '#',
    \   "profile": '#',
    \   "bashrc": '#',
    \   "bash_profile": '#',
    \   "mail": '>',
    \   "eml": '>',
    \   "bat": 'REM',
    \   "ahk": ';',
    \   "vim": '"',
    \   "tex": '%',
    \ }

function! ToggleComment()
    if has_key(s:comment_map, &filetype)
        let comment_leader = s:comment_map[&filetype]
        if getline('.') =~ '^\s*$'
            " Skip empty line
            return
        endif
        if getline('.') =~ '^\s*' . comment_leader
            " Uncomment the line
            execute 'silent s/^' . comment_leader . '//'
        else
            " Comment the line
            execute 'silent s/^/\1' . comment_leader . ' /'
        endif
    else
        echo "No comment leader found for filetype"
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-C> :call ToggleComment()<CR>
vnoremap <C-C> :call ToggleComment()<CR>
```

When I try to comment out this kitty.conf code, it doesn't work.
Instead it shows "No comment leader found for filetype" as per my vimrc code

```
map ctrl+v        paste_from_clipboard
map shift+insert paste_from_clipboard

font_family      Hack Regular Nerd Font
bold_font        Hack Bold Nerd Font
italic_font      Hack Italic Nerd Font
bold_italic_font Hack Bold Italic Nerd Font
```

Comment: Please give details on what your problem is. You say you want it to work for those filetypes; they are configured in the dictionary. Is something not working? If so, please provide a recipe that demonstrates this. It might look like “1. Edit foo.conf 2. Insert hello world 3. Press C-c. It should comment out the line but instead X happens”

Comment: thanks for the update though

Comment: i am using gvim on windows.. i tried `:debug`.. but it doesn't work.. vim returns it as error

Comment: For example, `:debug call ToggleComment()` ?

Comment: it shows this https://i.imgur.com/66qTg40.jpg

Comment: `:help debug`, you want step or next probably

Comment: I can't reproduce with the code in the question either. Is it limited to `kitty.conf`? Is the filetype there somehow different from regular conf files in your setup?

Comment: no.. this code should do the same with regular conf files.. but it doesn't